# Angular - slowly typing in modal window

Tags: angular

I have modal window with text input and when I typed to this text input, it was slowly. This text input hasnt any events (only ngModel). Here is image from chrome profiler:
[image]

I don't know where can be a problem. If its needed I can show you some code.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to help you without looking your code. Share the realted code here

Comment: Please share the HTML and Angular code please, a plunker would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It wasnt in modal window, problem was impure pipe. My code is something like this:

```
<input type="text" ngModel="message.text">
<div *ngFor="let m in messages">
  {{m.text}} - {{m.date|my-format}}
</div>
```

**MyFormat.Pipe.ts:**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'my-format', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {}
```

In `messages` array was a lot of records and when I typed to textbox, pipe run again for all records.

**Solution**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'my-format', pure: true})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {}
```